# infinite value while using cumulative constraint

Tags: minizinc

I am stuck with a cumulative constraint I seem not to use properly, I seek for help ! :)

I have tasks with precedence and, for some of them, required & forbidden resources.
I need to decide when to start a task & who to assign to it.

To do so, I'm using an array of decision variable resource_allocation:

```
array[Tasks, Resources] of var 0..1: resource_allocation; %Selection of resources per task.
```

To manage the required/forbidden resources, I used the following:

```
% Mandatory & Forbidden constraint allocation
constraint forall(t in Tasks, r in resource_required[t])(resource_allocation[t,r]=1);
constraint forall(t in Tasks, r in resource_forbidden[t])(resource_allocation[t,r]=0);
```

resource_required being set of int storing the resources number that are required/forbidden.

Each resource represents 1 worker, and each worker can only perform one task at a time, so I am trying to state that, for every resources, the cumsum of allocation can at max be 1.

It might be important to note that start is also a decision variable.

```
 % Constraint allocated to only one task at a time
    constraint forall(t in Resources)(
        cumulative(start, duration, [resource_allocation[t, r] | t in Tasks], 1)
    );
```

Doing so, I always end up with the following error

```
JC:70.12-82
  in call 'cumulative'
cumulative:21-3.49-7
  in binary '/\' operator expression
cumulative:25-3.49-7
  in if-then-else expression
cumulative:26-5.48-9
  in binary '/\' operator expression
cumulative:30-5.48-9
  in if-then-else expression
cumulative:47.7-32
  in call 'fzn_cumulative'
fzn_cumulative:4-9.20-17
  in let expression
fzn_cumulative:8-13.20-17
  in if-then-else expression
fzn_cumulative:10-17.19-17
  in let expression
fzn_cumulative:12.21-74
  in variable declaration for 'late'
  in call 'max'
    with i = <expression>
MiniZinc: evaluation error: arithmetic operation on infinite value
Process finished with non-zero exit code 1.
```

I need a little guidance, I looked in the source code of fzn_cumulative, but I don't get what is going on.
Thanks !

Comment: It would help to see the full model (with a small dataset), e.g. how `start` is defined.

Comment: start is defined as `array [Tasks] of var int: start;` I will post the entire model, but for now I am blocked by the 90 minutes limit.

Comment: Actually, problem solved. By defining  start that way: `array [Tasks] of var 1..t_max: start;`, it works properly. Not sure I fully understand why. Thanks for your comment that helped me!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might consider to limit the domains of your decisions variables.
`int` is unlimited (disregarding the limited number of bits per int) and may lead to overflow situations or complaints about infinite values.

```
include "globals.mzn";
set of int: Tasks = 1..3;
set of int: Resources = 1..3;
set of int: Durations = 1..10;
set of int: Times = 1..1000;

% Use this editor as a MiniZinc scratch book
array[Tasks, Resources] of var 0..1: resource_allocation; %Selection of resources per task.
array [Tasks] of var Times: start;
array [Tasks] of var Durations: duration;
array [Tasks] of set of Resources: resource_required = [{1,2},{2,3},{3}];
array [Tasks] of set of Resources: resource_forbidden = [{},{1},{1}];

% Mandatory & Forbidden constraint allocation
constraint forall(t in Tasks, r in resource_required[t])(resource_allocation[t,r]=1);
constraint forall(t in Tasks, r in resource_forbidden[t])(resource_allocation[t,r]=0);

% Constraint allocated to only one task at a time
% Changed "t in Resources" to "r in Resources"
    constraint forall(r in Resources)( 
        cumulative(start, duration, [resource_allocation[t, r] | t in Tasks], 1)
    );
```

Comment: This was exactly it, I had to bound start from 1 to t_max. Thanks